# filter particular column value based on rows using mdx or in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, mdx, ssrs-2012, mdxstudio

[image]
I have defectcode 0,1,2... what i need is, for service failure column mentioned in the image i need only values for defect >0 and it(servicefailure) should not display value for defect 0.

so that i can use these value to sum up in report or 
give me an expression to filter defect 0 for only service failure column.
like: iif(fields!defect <>0,fields!servicefailure,0) but this isn't working.
Here defect is dimension and servicefailure column in measure.

Comment: Please add the code you currently are using for servicefailure